# how to increase input file name in a for loop in R

Tags: r, csv, for-loop, read.csv

I want to plot 10 different files with names `group1.csv` to `group10.csv`, so I have created for loop which runs for **i = 1 to 10**, but how to import these group files in the loop?

How to increase file name with 'i' e.g. groupi.csv?

File group1 to group10 having three different columns, how to select any two columns as x-axis and y-axis in barplot?

```
i <- 1
for (i in 1:10) {
  group <- read.csv("E:/R/r/Dummy Data_globalspace/group'i'.csv")
  barplot(group)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `paste` function:

```
filename <- paste0("E:/R/r/Dummy Data_globalspace/group", i, ".csv")
group    <- read.csv(filename)
```

Comment: if these files , **group1 to group10** are already shown in global environment then there is no need to do `read.csv`..in this case how to do it..means i directly want to import these files from global environment simultaneously increase their names lfom group1 to group10

Comment: Then you can look into using `eval()` along with my answer.  Your comment does not give enough information for a complete answer.  You might want to ask a new question rather than changing the one you already asked.

Comment: i askedd new question but nobody replied me there..can you please look it once...   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674544/increase-the-name-of-input-exported-from-global-environment-in-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste()` for concatinating and then use it as parameter.

```
i <- 1
for (i in 1:10)

{

myfilename <- paste("E:/R/r/Dummy Data_globalspace/group", i, ".csv",sep="")
group    <- read.csv(myfilename)

barplot(group)

}
```

Comment: if these files , **group1 to group10** are already shown in global environment then there is no need to do `read.csv`..in this case how to do it..means i directly want to import these files from global environment simultaneously increase their names lfom group1 to group10